# To execute a batch file each time a Users login

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, userappdatapath

I've a batch file which does copying of some files in the CommonAppData folder(C:\ProgramData) to the logged in User's Local App Data. What I would like to do is to execute this on each  different login. I could find many articles talking about the execution of batch files in startup but I would like to know how the same is done while login.

Comment: This would be a better fit on ServerFault.com as it's more of an administrative/support task than a programming question.

Comment: okay. thanks. would move to ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

The best way to trigger any action at login (at least under Windows 7) is to use "scheduled tasks".

Another common (but less robust) way is to copy the .bat file (or link to the .bat file) to the user's startup directory.

Comment: some way I could make this do programatically?